# Hide SelectButton in Gridview on SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, gridview, linkbutton

I have a Gridview with a SelectButton in a templatefield. Once the Button is pushed I want this button to be hidden. I do

```
LinkButton SLCT = (LinkButton)GridView01.SelectedRow.FindControl("ButtonSelect");
SLCT.Visible = false;
```

I tried to declare the button in many different ways, using Row index, Cell index. but it always throws the following exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

All parameters to specify the control are 100% correct but the error is always the same.

Anyone on this?
Martin

Comment: Have u used the debugger to see what's `null`?

Comment: It's the SLCT button that is null

Comment: Are u sure that the `SelectedRow` has a control `ButtonSelect`?

Comment: I applied the same logic to hide a Label in the same GridView:   Label SLCT = GridView01.SelectedRow.FindControl("LabelSalesprice") as Label; SLCT.Visible = false and it works. Something wrong with using the LinkButton in an analog way? <asp:LINKButton ID="SelectButton" runat="server" CommandName ="Select">

Comment: That hurts. I checked it a million times "SelectButton" is NOT "ButtonSelect" That happens if you do corrections manually.